# Remove empty rows when append data to .csv file in python, the row jump 1 empty row every i add the data

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my code for append data to csv in python

```
airtemp = rootgrp.variables['Tair_f_inst'][0][0][0]
lon = rootgrp.variables['lon'][0]
lat = rootgrp.variables['lat'][0] 

row = ['2014', '12', '31', '01', 'ADR', lat, lon, airtemp]
with open('D:\Python\gg.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile).writerow(row)
csvFile.close()
```

if i run the file many times the csv wiil be like this 
[the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO9Z9.png)

```
Year,Month,Date,Time,plant,latitude,longitude,airtemp
2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257

2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257

2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257

2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257

2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257

2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257

2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257
```

how can i remove that empty rows every i append the data from python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is adding `delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n'` to `writer = csv.writer(csvFile).writerow(row)`, so the code will be like this:

```py
airtemp = rootgrp.variables['Tair_f_inst'][0][0][0]
lon = rootgrp.variables['lon'][0]
lat = rootgrp.variables['lat'][0] 

row = ['2014', '12', '31', '01', 'ADR', lat, lon, airtemp]
with open('D:\Python\gg.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',).writerow(row)
csvFile.close()
```

and the CSV output will change from this:

```
Year,Month,Date,Time,plant,latitude,longitude,airtemp
2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257
2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257
2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257
2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257
2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257
2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257
2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257
```

to this:

```
Year,Month,Date,Time,plant,latitude,longitude,airtemp
2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257
2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257
2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257
2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257
2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257
2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257
2014,12,31,01,ADR,-2.375,115.375,297.5257
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `airtemp` ends with a new line. Try this:

```
row = ['2014', '12', '31', '01', 'ADR', lat, lon, airtemp.strip()]
```